# LocalStorage value keeps disappearing from the page after onsubmit

Tags: javascript, local-storage, onsubmit

For some reasons the value "image-path.jpg" is just appearing on my page the time it takes for the page to refresh after submitting the form. How can I keep the value "image-path.jpg" on the page? I'm trying to achieve this with localStorage, but the value keeps disappearing.

```
function myFunction() {
  localStorage.setItem("path","image-path.jpg");
  //get value of from local storage
  var results = localStorage.getItem("path")
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = results;
}
```

Comment: My guess is you don't call `event.preventDefault()` in your submit event handler, which causes the page to reload and return to its initial state. In other words, the problem is not with localStorage but with the statefulness of your page.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is preventing to post the values from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your html looks something like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <label for="control"> Insert some value: </label>
    <input type="text" id="control" name="control"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
</form>
<div id="result"> Previous value: </div>
```

You'll want to set the submitted value in localStorage:

```
document.getElementById("myForm")
  .addEventListener("submit", function () {
    var imagePath = document.getElementById("control").value;
    localStorage.setItem("path", imagePath);
  });
```

Then retrieve it when the page loads:

```
var imagePath = localStorage.getItem("path");
document.getElementById("result").textContent += imagePath || 'Nothing';
```

Check out this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/local-storage-access-on-submit).